# Got 3 HP Proliant DL365 G1 for really, really cheap. Can I run Hyper-v or ESXI?

Tags: virtualization, hp-proliant

Title. I got them for really cheap, including the rack, and I was thinking of setting them to virtualize stuff for home use and for some labs. 
First I tried to install Windows Server 2019 (I have MSDN Subscription so licenses are ok), got an error. Then Every single image (Windows Servers from 2003 to 2019, Ubuntu Server latest, EXSI from 5.5 and upwards) I tried to boot up from,  getting the same error (Ilegal Opcode).

Since these servers are really old, do any of you remember what can I run? Do I need to do special stuff that a guy like me with only PCs have never done?

Comment: for the records, I've tried all I know for the last 2 weeks. Really cheap = $40 for the 3 of them with 5 Hdds each

Comment: Sorry but you paid $40 more than they are worth.

Comment: I bet, I just want to run something out of them

Comment: Sounds like you're booting from the hard drive, and not the ISO image. Check your boot sequence in the BIOS.

Comment: I have a mini-ITX server at home, jetway motherboard, fanless and take around 5watt of power (costed me around 100$), and sadly Iam sure my lab run faster than on a 365g1. I say that as to lab, no need to have server hardware

Answer (score 3):

You should not run any modern hypervisors on this server hardware. That model of HP server was released in 2007, and anything more than a decade old is a bad choice for a new installation.

Please review the [HPE Quickspecs](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=c04282518) for your systems.

VMware technically supports the CPU. If you want to be thorough, please post your actual errors.

A more likely issue is that your HP Smart Array RAID controller and drives simply need to be reinitialized. From the BIOS utility, delete the Logical Drives and re-create them... *Then* install your OS of choice.

[image]

Comment: Reinitializing the RAID array seems like the thing to do. I guess he is running into [this issue](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/407403) and for some reason the server isn't actually trying to boot from his ISO image but from the old RAID array.